# How to use DATETIME in WHERE clause in SAS PROC SQL

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I have this data in a SAS table: 01Sep2016:21:31:27

I want to do this:

```
PROC SQL;
UPDATE lib1.tablename1
set Valid_From = '2000-01-01 00:00:00'dt
WHERE Valid_From = '1Sep2016:21:31:26'dt;
QUIT;
```

But the WHERE clause doesn't match. What is the correct format for the datetime value?

Comment: I assume the difference in milliseconds between your stated value and the value in the code (27 vs 26) is a typo!

Answer (score 4):

You were very nearly there - try this:

```
PROC SQL;
UPDATE lib1.tablename1
set Valid_From = '01jan2000:00:00:00'dt
WHERE Valid_From = '01Sep2016:21:31:26'dt;
QUIT;
```